# How to create self enclosing element javascript XML DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing, xmldom

I want to create element like,

```
<Object name="object name" value="object value" />
```

but every time i end up with

```
<Object name="object name" value="object value"></Object>
```

I am using this code piece

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
newel = xmlDoc.createElement("Object");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Page")[0];
x.appendChild(newel);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: as per w3c standards it automatically close the element, not self closed. there's no way to do...

Comment: Ok thanks, is there any workaround for this? other than string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two representations of an empty XML element are perfectly equivalent. In the DOM representation, you have an element of name "Object" that does not have any (non-attribute) children. If you parse the two XML strings, you will get exactly the same DOM.

The different textual representation depends on how you serialise your DOM tree into text.

Comment: how can I serialize DOM tree with one option? I am using `var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);`

Comment: I fear there is no way to customise the XMLSerializer to render empty elements as self-closing elements.

If you really need that, the easiest way is probably to use string manipulation.